# TabControl staticresource path icons dissapear on tab's switch

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabs, tabcontrol, staticresource

I don't seem to find an answer how to make reusable path-icons in wpf. I suspect that my problem is the same with using Image visuals instead of Source but can't figure out how to fix this for Paths.

I have a tab control with separate custom controls in the tabs. Each of them have buttons with 'path' content.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonIconStyle}"
        Content="{StaticResource RefreshIcon}" 
        Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"/>
```

Where icon is:

```
<Path x:Key="RefreshIcon" Stretch="Uniform" 
      Fill="{StaticResource ButtonIconColor}" Data="..."/>
```

I need this Uniform stretch so I also tried ViewBox, but that didn't help.

The first tab with this icon I open is shown normally (it can be any tab, not first in tabcontrol). But after switching to another tab with the same defined button and switching back to prev tab the icon in the first one is no longer visible. It happend only with icons that are the same (if icon is not present in the second tab it will remain visible).

[image: tab control behaviour]

What can I do about it?

Btw my Buttons are styled, but the same thing happend when they were just simple rectangular buttons with path content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your path is referenced using `StaticResourceExtension` in multiple places (by different instances of `Button`). Since `Path` is a `FrameworkElement` and it can only occur once in the visual tree, what happens is if you load the second tab (thus loading the `Path` into this tab, it gets unloaded from the previous tab (to satisfy the said condition). Observe that it will always be visible in the last tab selected.

In order to resolve this problem you need to set `x:Shared="False"` on your `Path` in the resources dictionary - this way whenever it is referenced using `StaticResouceExtension` a copy will be returned rather than the actual instance from the resources dictionary, each of which will be loaded and stay in the visual tree as expected.